# GKE Cost Allocation supported SKUs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

The GKE Cost Allocation feature has this limitation in [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cost-allocations) :

```
GKE cost allocation supports the following resource SKU types:

    Compute Engine VM Instance Core SKUs
    Compute Engine VM Instance RAM SKUs
    Compute Engine VM Instance GPU SKUs
```

I can't find these names in the types of machines available, what does the above mean in actual machine types ? M{1,2}, C{2,2D} and A2 only ?
We're using E2 machines and all I'm getting in the bigquery table are unsupported SKUs lines, so presumably E2 doesn't fall in the core category ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The information above regarding the SKUs is the Compute Engine machine type that you are using on your GKE and upon checking on the [Machine series comparison](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-resource) E2 machine type is included in the core category as a [Cost-optimized machine series](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-resource#general-purpose_machine_family_guide), you can refer to this documentation for the list of [SKU Groups](https://cloud.google.com/skus/sku-groups) on Compute Engine.

Comment: So you're saying it should be supported ? Then it must not be working because they're spot instances, I guess

Comment: Yes, it should be supported for your reference here's another list for [Spot Preemptible E2 VMs](https://cloud.google.com/skus/sku-groups/spot-preemptible-e2-vms) and for your enlightenment about [How Spot VMs work in GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/spot-vms#how-it-works) see this documentation for reference.

Comment: Well, then I have no ideas left on why it's saying not supported. Oh well

Answer (score 0):

Quite often if you can't find the data you are looking for it turns out to be the wrong table or the basic one. Ensure you are using the detailed billing export and it usually has 'resource' somewhere in the name.